# Unity 2D - How can I create multiple animations for a single character?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a character and for each action of that character I am using a different drawing with different body parts.
I created a folder with my character name and added the body parts and the animation of the first action.
I want to create my second animation but i don't want my first one to be deleted.
How can I add my animation (and I suppose I have to add the new body parts too) without deleting my first animation? Do I need to create another character and somehow switch them with the code when I would like to do an action (Moving for instance)?
Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a software-related issue. Navigate to the Animation window and you should see this: [image]

Click on this and create your animation and then use the Animator Window to make the animations interact with each other. There are parameters that can be created to tell unity when an animation should be run. These can be created here:

[image]

Then use the Animator object to change these parameters in code such as:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Animation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            animator.SetBool("Run", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("Run", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! I'm having some problems with the logistics. I want to add animations to a character that require more body parts and effects. Does it all need to be under 1 character folder or do I have to split it between multiple ones

Comment: You could have all the other parts in the same character but disable them. Then enable them in the anination when you want to use them.

Comment: Ok cool! Thanks for the help!